# Video tag not working

Tags: php, video, html5-video

I have a problem with playing a video on my website using the video tag.
I have included different types of video .ogv and .mp4 , and still my video won't run.
I tried it on my localhost the videos are working perfectly but when trying online only the controls appear in gray color.

This is a link to the videos page: http://www.raymondyazbeck.com/videos.php?catId=2

This is my code:

```
<video width="900" height="506" controls autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" tabindex="0">
   <source src="videos/<?php echo $book[0]['videoName'] ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="videos/<?php echo $book[0]['videoName'] ?>.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

From investigating your website, I noticed [the following problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhHUP.png):

[image: 404 Errors]

This is a 404 error reported by the console. You need to upload your video files to your server in a location that can be found by the HTTP requests that you're making with those `video` tags.

In the future, you can use Chrome's Developer Tools or Mozilla's Firebug Extension to see front-end console errors (such as Javascript or load problems.)

Comment: what is that, a printscreen for ants? :P, +1 though